# Rename file to uppercase in the same directory using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, rename

I am trying to rename files in same Windows directory using Java -

`Before: -`

*C:/Temp/abG.txt*

`After: -`

*C:/Temp/ABG.TXT*

I have tried using `file.renameTo` but that did not work. Now I am trying to use -

```
Path source = file.toPath();
Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(file.getName().toUpperCase()));
```

Still no luck. Please help.

Comment: This does not work because filenames in windows are not case sensitive. You need to rename it to something else first (like "WindowsIsRubbish.txt", then you should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally issue is resolved.

It seems `file.renameTo` works fine on Windows. The path I mentioned was wrong, rectified it and code worked.

I was using path as `C:/Temp/Folder` it should be `C:/Temp/Folder/`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running but this logically should work.

```
  String newFilePath = oldFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(oldFile.getName(), oldFile.getName().toUpperCase());
  File newFile = new File(newFilePath);

  try {
    FileUtils.moveFile(oldFile, newFile);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would first add a check, if this is Windows or Linux/Unix/Mac. If it's Windows, there should be an intermediary step that renames the file to a temporary name (I would suggest using `System.currentMillis()` as a unique name) and then moving this file under the uppercase name. Otherwise, your code won't work under Windows, as it treats upper and lowercase names as the same file.

Comment: @vishram0709 Thanks but that did not help much :(

Comment: @carlspring thanks one correction `System.currentTimeMillis()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    String FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\HariBabuM\\Desktop\\file\\modify";
    File oldFile = new File(FILE_PATH, "fileWithCamelCase.txt");
    File newFile = new File(FILE_PATH, oldFile.getName().toLowerCase());

    oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
```